# Adding UIVibrancyEffect to a UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I layout a blurred background, and then a scrollview into which I place UILabels etc, some of which I would like to be vibrant, and some of which I would like to display as white text.

This works fine given a static view, as scrolling functionality is not needed. However, given that it is needed, I face the choice of putting the UILabel in the vibrancy.contentView (and adding vibrancy) or in the scrollview (and adding scrollability), but not both.

EDIT:

Here's a workaround:

```
UIBlurEffect * blur = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVibrancyEffect * vibrancy = [UIVibrancyEffect effectForBlurEffect:blur];

UIVisualEffectView * vs = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blur];
[vs setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:vs];

scroller = [UIScrollView new];
scroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, w, h-80);
scroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
scroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
scroller.delegate = self;
[vs addSubview:scroller];

vsv = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:vibrancy];
[scroller addSubview:vsv];

UIView * view = [UIView new]; //WITHOUT VIBRANCY
[vsv addSubview:view];

UIView * view = [UIView new]; //WITH VIBRANCY
view.frame = CGRectMake(20, yOff, w-40, 50);
[vsv.contentView addSubview:view];

vsv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, yOff); //RESIZE ALL
scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w, yOff);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put the label that you don't want to be vibrant into content view of `UIVisualEffectView * vs = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blur];`. Than any view added to visual effect view with UIVibrancyEffect will be vibrant and those who added to visual effect view with UIBlurEffect will be shown without vibrancy.

Comment: That works if we don't need scrolling. If it's a static view, we can just place them where they need to go. The problem is keeping the scrolling and vibrancy.

Comment: So you have static image that should be blurred and scrollable content which should have both vibrant and non vibrant blocks. Place blur effect view as primary content of UIScrollView (this view should have same size as content size of scroll view), than when you adding non vibrant blocks to scroll view add it to blur view and when you need block with vibrancy you should create separate UIVisualEffectView with vibrancy for every vibrant block. This will make all of your block scrollable and some of them will have vibrancy effect.

Comment: Yep, that's an option, but it includes adding more methods within scrollViewDidScroll compensating for the offset. I keep the blur at the back and then add the scroller, then add vibrancy views into the scroller. It turns out you don't need to add the vibrancy view to the blur.contentView.

Comment: That means it won't be "real" vibrancy, if you need to show vibrant views that takes background into consideration you should add it into blur view